# how to download entire folder from opengrok results

Tags: opengrok

How can we download entire folder/dir from the opengrok results? I know we can download file from the opengrok results but not quite sure for entire directory/folder.

Comment: Have you tried wget?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to download an entire folder using OpenGrok web, but in [this enhancement request](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/issues/2000), there's a suggestion to perform this task using "wget + mitmproxy + proxychains".